# Is it possible to extract the second line of text from MS Form using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I want to extract the second line of text on that MS form and save it as text file in my desktop.

I have tried the following:

Sub DownloadHeaderTextAsTXT()
Dim objHTTP As New WinHttp.WinHttpRequest
Dim objTextFile As Object
Dim objHTML As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Dim strText As String

```
objHTTP.Open "GET", "https://forms.office.com/Pages/ResponsePage.aspx?id=awcO9aWG80WHsD9NDsXpTtJCpW-P-dRKnllcB9VlAENUMEk4SU5PQ1BOSjZXM0lZREw0RjNRVFJRMy4u", False
objHTTP.Send

strHTML = objHTTP.responseText


Set objHTML = New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
objHTML.body.innerHTML = strHTML

For Each element In objHTML.all
    If element.tagName = "header" Then
        strText = element.innerText
        Exit For
    End If
Next

Set objTextFile = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").CreateTextFile(Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Documents\text.txt", True)

objTextFile.Write strText

objTextFile.Close


If strText <> "" Then
    MsgBox "The text was successfully downloaded as a .txt file to C:\headertext.txt"
Else
    MsgBox "The text was not found on the webpage"
End If
```

End Sub

but this isnot working, i wanted to extract the second line of text on that form.In this case the text is 20222, which i want to copy and paste it as text file on my computer.

Comment: Welcome Samundra! Please take some time to read the introduction to Stack Overflow and earn your first badge. We're a little bit different from other sites. Here's how...  https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is really a question about web scraping but anyways:

Try looking in this url insted for the actual form content:

`https://forms.office.com/handlers/ResponsePageStartup.ashx?id=awcO9aWG80WHsD9NDsXpTtJCpW-P-dRKnllcB9VlAENUMEk4SU5PQ1BOSjZXM0lZREw0RjNRVFJRMy4u`

it contains (among other things): `<b><span>20222</span></b>`.

How I found this (this is in firefox but other browsers should be similar):

1. Go to your URL which displays the form.
2. press F12 to open developer tools.
3. go to network tab.
4. press f5 to reload the page.
5. click on magnifying glass on the left side of the 2nd bar from the top to search resources.
6. type "20222" and hit enter to search for this text.
7. Url to resource which contains the text should be highlighted in the list.